AWS MQTT3 Websockets Connection Closed Unexpectedly
I'm trying to connect to AWS MQTT3 via websockets with authentication from Cognito, but I'm getting Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.. What might be the problem?
This is my method for getting GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse
    public GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse getCredentialsForIdentity(AuthenticationResultType accessToken, String identityId) {
        try (var client = CognitoIdentityClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .build()) {
            return client.getCredentialsForIdentity(
                    GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest.builder()
                            .identityId(identityId)
                            .logins(
                                    Map.of(
                                            "cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XGRz3CgoY",
                                            accessToken.idToken()))
                            .build());
        }
    }

After this I'm using GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse to obtain MqttClientConnection:
public MqttClientConnection buildConnection(String prefix,
                                            String region,
                                            String clientId,
                                            GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse credentialsForIdentity)  {
    try (var builder = AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder.newMtlsBuilderFromPath(null, null)) {
        MqttClientConnectionEvents callbacks = new MqttClientConnectionEvents() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionInterrupted(int errorCode) {
                log.error("Connection interrupted: " + errorCode + ": " + CRT.awsErrorString(errorCode));
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionResumed(boolean sessionPresent) {
                log.error("Connection resumed: " + (sessionPresent ? "existing session" : "clean session"));
            }
        };
        return builder.withEndpoint("%s-ats.iot.%s.amazonaws.com".formatted(prefix, region))
                .withWebsockets(true)
                .withConnectionEventCallbacks(callbacks)
                .withWebsocketSigningRegion(region)
                .withClientId(clientId)
                .withWebsocketCredentialsProvider(
                        new StaticCredentialsProvider.StaticCredentialsProviderBuilder()
                                .withAccessKeyId(  credentialsForIdentity.credentials().accessKeyId().getBytes(UTF_8))
                                .withSecretAccessKey(credentialsForIdentity.credentials().secretKey().getBytes(UTF_8))
                                .withSessionToken( credentialsForIdentity.credentials().sessionToken().getBytes(UTF_8))
                                .build())
                .build();
    }
}

and then when I'm trying to connect I'm getting previously mentioned error:
MqttClientConnection connection) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    try (connection) {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> connected = connection.connect();
        boolean sessionPresent = connected.get(); // <--- here!
    }
}


Have you verified that clientId is unique (multiple clients using the same client ID is a common cause of unexpected disconnections). docs "When a client connects to the message broker using a client ID that another client is using, the new client connection is accepted and the previously connected client is disconnected.".

I'm using UUID.randomUUID() so there is good chance that it's unique

I'm continuing this topic on GH https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2/issues/586
